# How do I draw text once a countdown ends?

Tags: software-engineering, timer, game-maker, text

I created a countdown in *Game Maker* using a variable of time. The countdown works properly and is displayed at the proper coordinates. However, when the countdown reaches zero, I want to make the countdown disappear and display "GO" instead.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to have two objects and then use instance_change() two swap into the next object when the countdown finishes.

**Example:**

```
if (countdown <= 0) {
    instance_change(obj_go, true);
}
```